# how to deploy and use travis-ci on cordova project to test browser, android etc

Tags: cordova, travis-ci

below is the Travis-ci config that I use, I want to know if Travis has a sample code or template for cordova for ios, android and browser etc for me to refer from, all google points me to are ionic flavors and they have deviate from the core too much to use as a reference

I tried this build 21 times and I really don't want to hit a rate limit, which I am sure is there, (no one instates vms for free lol)

```
language: android

node_js:
  - 5.5

notifications:
  email: false

sudo: true

branches:
  only:
  - master

android:
  components:
    - build-tools-25.0.2

install:
  - cd rotaract3220
  - sudo apt-get install npm
  - sudo npm install
  - sudo npm cache clean
  - sudo npm install -g cordova
  - echo y | android update sdk -u --filter android-22,android-23
  - ls
  - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

before_script:
  - cordova platform remove android
  - cordova platform add android

script:
  - cordova prepare
  - cordova build android --release -- --ant

release:
- exit 0
```

This is the error I keep getting, I have tried a symbolic link but seems to be a problem with nodejs? or something of the sorts

```
cordova platform remove android
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/init-package-json/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:9
    const syntaxErr = e.message.match(/^Unexpected token.*position\s+(\d+)/i)
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/init-package-json/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```